# VBA - Minimum/ Maximum Value for Date()

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a reason that the Excel functions of Min & Max are not working for the following code?

```
Sub minmaxtest()

Dim TEST_VALUES() As Date
ReDim TEST_VALUES(1 To 5, 1 To 1)

TEST_VALUES(1, 1) = 1
TEST_VALUES(2, 1) = 2
TEST_VALUES(3, 1) = 3
TEST_VALUES(4, 1) = 4
TEST_VALUES(5, 1) = 5

MsgBox Application.Max(TEST_VALUES)

End Sub
```

This problem does not exist in the case where `Dim TEST_VALUES() As Integer`, but occurs when declared it a Date.

I have tried to wrap the values that are assigned in `(CLng(CDate())`, eg, `TEST_VALUES(1, 1) = (CLnd(CDate(1))` but this also does not solve my problem of performing analysis on this date range (is this the correct name for this type of variable?) Thanks!

Comment: `Application.Max` and `WorksheetFunction` seem to be designed to work only with the`.Value2` types, because It returns 1 if you use ` As Currency`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `CDate` on each array item you will get `5` as the `Max`:

```
Sub minmaxtest()

Dim TEST_VALUES() As Integer
ReDim TEST_VALUES(1 To 5, 1 To 1)

TEST_VALUES(1, 1) = CDate(1)
TEST_VALUES(2, 1) = CDate(2)
TEST_VALUES(3, 1) = CDate(3)
TEST_VALUES(4, 1) = CDate(4)
TEST_VALUES(5, 1) = CDate(5)

MsgBox Application.Max(TEST_VALUES)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for a range of dates:

```
Sub d()

Dim a() As Variant

a = Range("a1:a5").Value2

Debug.Print CDate(Application.Max(a))

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice. Do you have an idea why this works with `Value2` but not with `Value` ? Help says *" Value2 property doesn’t use the Currency and Date data types"*. But with Value2 I get a nice date, with Value I get 00:00:00

Comment: It is that, which you wanted, it is saying that it uses the value for these, like 1000 instead of £1000, sounds like a contradiction.  This should explain with a cell with a date in `? activecell.Value
01/01/2016 <- result
? activecell.Value2
 42370 <- result`

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not critical, you can try:

```
MsgBox WorksheetFunction.Max(TEST_VALUES)
```

I am not sure if it works on arrays too.

Answer (score 0):

`Dim TEST_VALUES() As Variant` and it will work.
You defined variable as Date and you assign it integers.

Answer (score 0):

from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840751.aspx) :

> If the arguments contain no numbers, MAX returns 0 (zero).